# Select Feature Control OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I've been working with OpenLayers, and i made a layer tree (all layers are vector layers), and all this layers have features, what i want is to select those features through the select control.

I made the Select Feature Control but the problem it's that when i turn off one of those layers(i'm removing the layer from the map to turn it off), **the icon still there, it's like it doesn't turned off at all...**

I've tryed almost everything and i don't know why this could be happening...

Does anybody know how to solve this???

Comment: Please show relevant, if not all your code so we can help debug it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just remove all features from the layer each time you deactivate your control enstead of removing the layer.